# objective c UITableView not scrolling smooth with custom cell & views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios7

I want the tableview to display multiple images in each and every row which is scrollable. For this I'm using `UITableView` and `Custom UITableViewCell`, in custom tableView cell i'm generating scroll view with multiple views & images, So when i'm scrolling table its not scrolling smoothly its blinking. Can anyone suggest me to do this in better way?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
   // Products table view. 
   ProductCustomCell *cell = (ProductCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CatelogCell"] ;//] forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   if (cell == nil) { 
      cell = [[ProductCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CatelogCell"]; 
   } 
   cell.productCellDelegate = self; 
   [cell initProperties]; 
   [cell showProductsInScroll:catelogBundle];
}
```

Comment: How are you constructing your cells ? Show us the XIB ? Some code ?

Comment: What is displayed in the cells? Is there any content that needs to be loaded such as images that aren't in the app bundle?

Comment: If you have updates to your question, please edit it. Do not post huge chunks of code as a comment.

Comment: What's going on in initProperties and showProductsInScroll:?

Comment: I'm adding scroll view with multiple imageviews & buttons in custom cell to show in all rows.

Comment: initProperties: to remove all subviews in custom cell.

Comment: Add the code for these as well

Comment: showProductsInScroll: to add scroll view to custom cell with multiple images and buttons.

Comment: Any reason you're not using collectionView instead? Each cell could be an image, each row a separate section...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to scroll tableview smooth, several tips you should pay attention.

1. Cache the height of the rows (the table view can request this frequently),
   -- actually this point isn't the key point to block your tableview scroll.
2. Create a least-recently-used cache for the images used in the table (and invalidate all the inactive entries when you receive a memory warning)
   -- you can use SDWebImage to download image and cache them. And sometimes, you maybe want to cache some images that your tableview frequently used and these images could also don't free even you receive a memory warning if your current view is the top view。
3. Draw everything in the `UITableViewCell`'s `drawRect:` if possible avoid subviews at all costs (or if you require the standard accessibility functionality, the content view's `drawRect:`)
   -- it could save some cost, but it also may cost your more time to code and maybe hard to maintain codes. But it is really good to use less views on uitableviewcell, that will improve your performance.
4. Make your `UITableViewCell`'s layer opaque (same goes for the content view if you have one)
   -- please use layer opaque as less as possible.
5. Use the reusableCellIdentifier functionality as recommended by the `UITableView` examples/documentation
   -- you must follow this tips.
6. Avoid gradients/complicated graphical effects that aren't pre-baked into `UIImage`s
   -- like point 4.

of course, most time, if your tableview scroll not smooth, the main problem is that you load image in synchronize.

it's really good to use instruments to test the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably found a solution for your problem already, but if you're still looking, this worked for me. I'm also working on an app that involves displaying many pictures over several tableview cells.

I found out that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called pretty much every time the app loads a new cell onto the screen that is not already displayed, so every time you scroll up or down to new cells, this method keeps getting called even if some of the cells were on the screen earlier before you scrolled to a different position.

What I did was save cells and their corresponding indexpaths that were initialized for the first time into an array and when the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method gets called again, check if this cell was already initialized by checking if the indexpath is stored in my array of indexpaths.

```
@implementation MyViewController{
    NSMutableArray *cells;
    NSMutableArray *indexpaths;
}

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // check if in array
    if ([indexpaths containsObject:indexPath]){
        return cells[indexPath.row];
    }

    // otherwise, create a new one
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    // customizing cell
    // other stuff
    ...

    // finally save the cell and indepath for checking later
    [cells addObject:cell];
    [indexpaths addObject:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution. UITableView has a built in process of reusing cells. Look into the methods dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: or 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:. As soon as a cell scrolls off screen, it is dequeued, then reused by the next cell scrolling into view. If you have more cells than can be displayed at once, using the dequeuing will result in a smaller memory footprint than allocating a cell for every single row. The more cells you have, the more the memory footprint difference will be apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you may be allocating objects in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView . So instead of allocating any type of object there allocate in its ProductCustomCell class or create it in its xib file .

Comment: Yes actually this is what i'm doing so far, I'm allocating scroll view object, UIView & UILabel in ProductCustomCell class for each rows.

Comment: Avoid this , it will automatically start scrolling smoothly

Comment: And if i succeeded in helping you out , you can accept my answer so other users also may find this post beneficial :P

Answer (score 0):

I would like add a simple method in addition to TinyMonk's answer. If you make uitableview using custom cell, then make sure the clip subview option ticked right both for table and custom cell. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of Leo C han, I have updated it for Swift3.

```
var manualCells = NSMutableArray()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // check if in array
   if manualCells.contains(indexPath) {
      return manualCells.object(at: indexPath.row) as! UITableViewCell
   }

   let cell = self.tableViewReference.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell

   // fill the cell...     

   manualCells.insert(cell, at: indexPath.row)
   return cell
}
```

Note, this is for tables containing one section.