# UITableViewController not showing up cells when re-visit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unwind-segue

I have a MAIN camera View (camera) and a TABLE view (photo list) connected by segue in interface builder. 
For the table View I decided to build it on my own (UIViewController with TableView inside, cells are loaded in from a XIB with its own class)

When I run the application and travel from Camera view to Table view, everything works fine, cell background colour is shown, list can be scrolled with no problems too. (Reuse cells no problems)

Then I unwind segue back to the Camera view and come back to Table view again, the number of cells is correct but all are empty cells.

I have NSLog for each cells, the frame has been changed, and autoSize disappeared. Why would that happen ? Do I need to do some clean up when I unwind the segue so the next time it will start the UIViewController from scratch like the first time ?

any hints would be appreciated. 
Thank you !

```
// FIRST TIME TO TABLE VIEW
<galleryCell: 0x17516300; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 480 77); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x175166a0>>

// SECOND TIME TO TABLE VIEW 
<galleryCell: 0x175a4910; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x17513d10>>
```

[UPDATE] source code

```
// TableController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tv;
@property (nonatomic,strong)  NSArray *data;
@end
```

[UPDATE full .m file]

```
//
//  TableController.m
//  blurCam
//
//  Created by KDS on 3/25/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 KDS. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableController.h"
#import "galleryCell.h"
#import "UIButtonExt.h"

BOOL nibRegistered=NO;

@implementation TableController

+(UIBarButtonItem*) backButton: (id)target selector:(SEL)selector{

    UIViewController* controller=(UIViewController*)target;
    [controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    UIImage* backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"detail_back.png"];
    UIButtonExt* backBtn = [UIButtonExt buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, backImg.size.width/3.0 , backImg.size.height/3.0)];
    [backBtn setImage:backImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[TableController backButton:self selector:@selector(back)];

    // get document folder file list
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    _data=[self listFileAtPath:documentsDirectory];

    [self.tv reloadData];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_tv reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSArray *)listFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    //-----> LIST ALL FILES <-----//
    NSLog(@"LISTING ALL FILES FOUND");

    int count;
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
    return directoryContent;
}

// LAYER TABLE !
//
#pragma mark-
#pragma mark Table view data source method


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_data count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // set a tag
    static NSString *iden=@"galleryCell";

    // use nib as cell design

    if(nibRegistered==NO) {
        UINib *nib=[UINib nibWithNibName:@"galleryCell" bundle:nil];
        [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:iden];
        nibRegistered=YES;
    }

    // ask for reuse ?
    galleryCell *cell=(galleryCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:iden];
    if(cell == nil){
        NSLog(@"NILLLLLL");
        cell = [[galleryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:iden];
    }

    cell.btn1.hidden=NO;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[_data objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath]];

    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    NSLog(@"image to load %@",imgPath);

    [cell.btn1 setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSLog(@"~~~%@",cell);
    NSLog(@"~~~hidden %d",cell.hidden);


    return cell;

}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       return 77;
}

//
//
//
//

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }

//

-(void) back {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"cameraSegue" sender: self];
}


@end
```

and here's the outlet connections of TableController
[image]

and the outlet Connection of galleryCell.XIB

[image]

Comment: are you calling tableview reloadData at any point? is it in viewDidLoad: or viewWillAppear:?

Comment: Show your code. The implementation of tableview datasource and the methods related view of a view controller.

Comment: @RomyIlano yup inside viewWillAppear: - thx !

Comment: @AdeelMiraj added codes of the table part above - thank you !

Comment: This code looks apparently fine. Are you doing something with the tv outlet elsewhere in the code? If possible, please add your complete .m file and the prepare for segue method.

Comment: When I NSLog cell.hidden it returns YES but I set it to NO before the return but that didn't help

Comment: You `viewWillAppear:` method is missing a call to super: `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`

Comment: oops Yes Thank you . Added back in, but it didn't help the situation.

Comment: When I NSLog cell.btn1 at re-visit -> they all become (null) 
So a conclusion that I can make is:

--- when the cells are accessed from [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:iden] they work fine

--- and when the cells init from if(cell== NIL), they don't quite work.

Comment: OK here's what's working
` // ask for reuse ?
    galleryCell *cell=(galleryCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:iden];
    if(cell == nil){
        NSLog(@"NILLLLLL");
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"galleryCell"  owner:self  options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"NILL-> %@",cell);
    }`

Comment: but another problem is, Why is the table view performing action so "laggy" ? 
when I swipe through the table view, it is not smooth at all but a little bit jumpy (stop a bit and move a bit)

Comment: To Fix non-smoooth UITableView Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280108/objective-c-uitableview-not-scrolling-smooth-with-custom-cell-views. Also for the above code, I have an unneeded step to load image. Comment that NSData line out and everything work smooth and nice. NSString *imgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[_data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        //NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath]];
        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:imgPath];

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what's working 
this line won't load the XIB

```
cell = [[galleryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:iden];
```

replace this line of code in the .m file

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"galleryCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

then it is running with no problems.