# iOS Tableview Feed Display like in Facebook [Scrolling Issue]

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, tableview, feed

I created and app that shows feeds like in facebook, which includes Like, Comments count, and a recent comment

And it works fine, but when scrolling it is not smooth, it scrolls like jerk [Stops and Scrolls]

I searched google for this, i found the below references

[objective c UITableView not scrolling smooth with custom cell & views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280108/objective-c-uitableview-not-scrolling-smooth-with-custom-cell-views)

I used the Cache to store the loaded images, and retrived them from the cache if they available

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html

I checked the speed by creating `UITableViewCell` in code as well as in `XIB` file(Loaded from nib) with `reuseidentifier`, but both are same

Can anybody suggest that how can i get smooth scroll,
Or is there any other way to get View as Facebook Feeds

```
//MyFeedClass
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.postsList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedPostDisplay") as! FeedPostDisplay;
        let temp_feed = feeds[indexPath.section];
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.configureCell(temp_feed, index: indexPath.section, is_add_photos: is_add_photos);
        return cell;
    }
//UITableViewCellClass    
func configureCell(feedData: Feed, index: Int, is_add_photos: Bool){
            feedAuthorBtn.tag = index;
            feedImageBtn.tag = index;
            commentAuthorsBtn.tag = index;
            likeBtn.tag = Int(feedData.id)!;
            commentBtn.tag = index;
            settingBtn.tag = index;


            //Feed Profile Image
            if(!feedData.user.user_media.profile_pics.large.isEmpty)
            {
                let placeholder = UIImage(view: loadingView(CGSizeMake(feedAuthor.frame.width, feedAuthor.frame.height)));
                feedAuthor.load(feedData.user.user_media.profile_pics.large, placeholder: placeholder){ URL, image, error, cacheType, identity in
                    if cacheType == CacheType.None {
                        let transition = CATransition()
                        transition.duration = 0.5
                        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
                        self.feedAuthor.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
                        self.feedAuthor.image = image;
                        self.feedAuthor.clipsToBounds = true;
                    }
                }
                feedAuthor.layer.cornerRadius = feedAuthor.frame.width/2;
                feedAuthor.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
                feedAuthor.clipsToBounds = true;
            }
            else
            {
                feedAuthor.image = UIImage(view: noPicView(CGSizeMake(feedAuthor.frame.width, feedAuthor.frame.height)));
            }

            feedAuthorName.text = feedData.user.username;

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d";
            feedDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(feedData.timestamp);

            //Feed Image
            if !feedData.post_media[0].large.isEmpty
            {
                let placeholder = UIImage(view: loadingView(CGSizeMake(feedImage.frame.width, feedImage.frame.height)));
                feedImage.load(feedData.post_media[0].large, placeholder: placeholder){ URL, image, error, cacheType, identity in
                    if cacheType == CacheType.None {
                        let transition = CATransition()
                        transition.duration = 0.5
                        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
                        self.feedImage.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
                        self.feedImage.image = image;
                        self.feedImage.clipsToBounds = true;
                    }
                }
                feedImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
                feedImage.clipsToBounds = true;
            }

            //Feed Like Image
            likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "like.png");
            if feedData.post_is_liked
            {
                likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "like-selected.png");
            }

            //Feed Likes Count
            likesCount.text = feedData.post_likes_count;


            //Feed Comments Count
            commentsCount.text = feedData.post_comments_count;


            if(!feedData.post_recent_comments.user.user_media.profile_pics.large.isEmpty)
            {
                let placeholder = UIImage(view: loadingView(CGSizeMake(commentAuthorsImage.frame.width, commentAuthorsImage.frame.height)));
                commentAuthorsImage.load(feedData.post_recent_comments.user.user_media.profile_pics.large, placeholder: placeholder){ URL, image, error, cacheType, identity in
                    if cacheType == CacheType.None {
                        let transition = CATransition()
                        transition.duration = 0.5
                        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
                        self.commentAuthorsImage.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
                        self.commentAuthorsImage.image = image;
                        self.commentAuthorsImage.clipsToBounds = true;
                    }
                }
                commentAuthorsImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
            }
            else
            {
                if !feedData.post_recent_comments.id.isEmpty
                {
                    commentAuthorsImage.hidden = false;
                    commentAuthorsImage.image = UIImage(view: noPicView(CGSizeMake(commentAuthorsImage.frame.width, commentAuthorsImage.frame.height)));
                }
                else
                {
                    commentAuthorsImage.hidden = true;
                }
            }
            commentAuthorsImage.layer.cornerRadius = commentAuthorsImage.frame.width/2;
            commentAuthorsImage.clipsToBounds = true;
            commentAuthorsName.text = feedData.post_recent_comments.user.username;
            commentText.text = feedData.post_recent_comments.comment;
        }`
```

Comment: Please paste code from `cellForRow...` method...

Comment: @user1941284 i added the code please check

Comment: A lot is going on here...maybe try to comment out all code related to the images and see if it have impact on scrolling....and don't recreate `NSDateFormatter`, create it outside (viewDidLoad..) it's very slow to initialize

Comment: thank you, i'll check this and update you the result

Comment: I checked without images it works fine, but it needs to be worked when there is images
I also tried, that sending data to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and applies to cell in `willDisplayCell..`, then also it is jerking

Comment: i used async display kit to solve this issue, https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit, please suggest if there is any other alternatives to this

Comment: You should use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for loading images, load the image in the `cellForRow...` ,  use `imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "your_image_url")!,
                         placeholderImage: nil)` method

Comment: i already used a library for caching and showing images from cache, the asyncdisplaykit is for avoid jerking

Comment: "i used async display kit to solve this issue" - so is it solved or not? If not paste new code where you have used `asyncdisplaykit`